# How would I include gems using Rails 1.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am currently in an internship in which I am learning Ruby on Rails (mostly version 3.x).

I am responsible for a project which has been made way back using Rails 1.2.3 so this contains no such thing as a "Gemfile" so can someone show me the way I can include gems in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started Rails with the version 2.1 but probably it is the same thing. So with rails 2 you put your gem in `config/environnement.rb` like this (for example):

```
config.gem 'mislav-will_paginate', :version => '2.3.6', :lib => 'will_paginate', 
:source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

Next you run `rake gems:install`

Otherwise, other method, you have to just run in your shell `gem install yourgem`

I hope it is the same behaviour with Rails 1.2.3 but you will probably have issue with the version of the gems which will be incompatible with Rails 1.2.3

Comment: config.gems was new in rails 2.1. In 1.x there was nothing like this. You just installed the gems - gem install blah